# Generate ID Keys for MySQL Values

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I currently have a MySQL table that is formatted as such -

[image]

What I would like to do is move this data to a new table, but instead of having VARCHAR's for the part, location, and customer data, I would like to assign each of them autoincrementing id's based on the value. For example, part "DEF" would have an id of 1 and part "GHI" would have an id of 2. This is what the table would look like -

[image]

Is there an SQL query to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the values in the `part` and `loc` columns to be auto-incrementing integers, or you have type tables for `part` and `loc` respectively with auto-incrementing integers?

### Option-1:

Create the new table with a different name than the old one. Insert the entries into the new table from the old table mapping values to integers as you go.

```
INSERT INTO new_table_name (part, loc, quan, date, customer)
SELECT CASE
WHEN part = 'DEF' THEN 1
WHEN part = 'GHI' THEN 2
END
, CASE
WHEN loc = '...' THEN 1
WHEN loc = '...' THEN 2
WHEN loc = '...' THEN 3
END
, quan
, date
, customer
FROM original_table
```

### Option-2:

The following is a sample type table for part:

[image]

If you have a type table for `part` and `loc`, you can do something like this...

```
SELECT part.id
     , loc.id
     , quan
     , date
     , customer
  FROM original_table orig INNER JOIN part prt
        ON orig.part  = prt.value
       INNER JOIN loc
        ON orig.loc = loc.value
```

As far as I know, there is no way to use the auto-increment feature to directly generate values for the table you described.

Comment: Option two would be a lot better than the case statements in my opinion, that way if there is a new addition say ABC, you could easily assign it an id of 3 instead of going into the case statement and making the query longer

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to create new tables and populate it rather than trying to change the existing one (Especially, if your application is live and you are dealing with customer data).

I would suggest you to create a new schema as follows:

[Schema Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qGVY.png)

You can populate all the new tables using your existing table and assign all the primary keys to Auto-increment.

This helps you to scale your application and maintain it easily.